# Objects not in Viewport appearing in Render (Armatures/Rigging)

Tags: animation, rigging, eevee-render-engine

As you can see in the image below, I have a scene with three characters, which are all animated, either
doing a dance or just sitting idle. I downloaded a minecraft rig and uploaded it to Mixamo to get
them animated. Everything looks good until you hit render and see geometry that you do not see in the viewport. I'm trying to figure out what it is, and what I can do to get rid of it to have a normal render. Currently using EEVEE. Issue also persists in Cycles. I am pretty new to rigging so I assume the issue comes from somewhere in the armature that should not be rendered, but I just cannot figure this one out.

[image]

**Below are source files on Google Drive.**

This is the .blend for the scene >>> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jr0czbMXa2m8NSEZZBQlSQq14pE1q_9E/view?usp=sharing

This is the .blend for the rig I uploaded to Mixamo.com >>>
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XWKYnwbYEhUykrwM2hDitCmJzSD921mb/view?usp=sharing

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

These 3 objects were hidden in *Viewport* but not in *Render* as you can see in the *Outliner*:

[image]